# Got a Runtime error in C++ runtime error: addition of unsigned offset in Leetcode

Tags: c++, runtime-error

While solving Longest Consecutive Sequence in Leetcode i am getting this error but i am not getting why i am getting it.

> runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x603000000070
> overflowed to 0x60300000006c (stl_vector.h) SUMMARY:
> UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior

```
int longestConsecutive(vector<int>& nums) {
        sort(nums.begin(),nums.end());
        
        int curr = 1;
        int longest = 1;
        for(int i =0;i<nums.size();i++){
            if(nums[i] != nums[i - 1] )//The numbers can be same
            {
                if(nums[i] == nums[i - 1]  +1){
                    curr += 1;
                }
                else{   ///Update only when the distorted sequence is found
                    longest = max(longest,curr);
                    curr = 1;    
                }
            }
        }
        return max(curr,longest);
    }
```

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve] that everyone can reproduce!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that on first for loop iteration you get i=0 and check if `nums[i] != nums[i-1]` so it becomes `nums[0] != nums[-1]` which is UB because `nums[-1]` is uninitialized and does not belong to vector data actually.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the `for`, the first of `i` value is `0`, and then by `nums[i-1]`, it throws the exception.